# How to host websocket behind nginx reverse proxy

Tags: docker, nginx, websocket, proxy, reverse-proxy

On my **VPS** I only have one port and this is the reason why I use **proxer** - a dockerized nginx reverse proxy where you provide domain names and local ports to which it should be redirected.

I have successfully set up **socket.io** server with **polling** transport (as it uses http methods) but I would like to use **websocket** transport and this is where it fails. It tells me it can't estabilish `wss://` connection to this url.

This is nginx reverse proxy code I am using:

```
for cfg in $(cat /config); do
    domain=$(echo $cfg | cut -f1 -d=)
    destination=$(echo $cfg | cut -f2 -d=)
    echo ">> Building config for $domain";

    config=$(cat <<EOF
server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name  $domain;
    location / {
        proxy_pass $destination;
        proxy_set_header Host \$host;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade \$http_upgrade;
        #proxy_set_header Connection \$connection_upgrade;
        proxy_ssl_name \$host;
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        proxy_ssl_verify off;
        proxy_ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For \$remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto \$scheme;
        proxy_read_timeout 120;
        proxy_send_timeout 120;
        proxy_connect_timeout 120;
    }
}
EOF
)
    
    # append new config to the end of nginx config file
    echo "$config" >>$out
done
```

I noticed that this line is commented out and I read that it is needed for `wss://`:

```
#proxy_set_header Connection \$connection_upgrade;
```

Why is it commented out?
Will changing this line affect http proxy?
What changes should I do to allow wss:// on one of domains

Comment: Yes, according to this manual: https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/ you should uncomment this line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tool has pretty much everything what is needed to set up nginx reverse proxy.

Note that it won't support `wss://` out of the box though due to this commented line in its config.

```
#proxy_set_header Connection \$connection_upgrade;
```

Uncomment it, rebuild and have a happy reverse proxy which supports `wss://` :)